# Imported Aperture library into Photos, "Show Referenced File in Finder" does nothing

Tags: finder, photos, aperture

I just finished importing my Aperture library into Photos using the official import process. My Aperture library used referenced masters on an external drive, and I had my external drive connected during the import process.

With my external drive still connected, nothing happens when I two-finger click on a thumbnail and choose "Show Referenced File in Finder." Any ideas?

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184578/open-location-of-a-photo-in-finder-from-photos-app inc answers & comments

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, which seemed like it had something to do with access permissions. Try the following:

1. Pick a random photo for which "Show Referenced File in Finder" does nothing.
2. Select it and hit space to view it.
3. Photos will pop up a dialog saying that it can't access some files outside the Photos library and will ask you to select a certain folder (for me it was the root of all my referenced files).

After I'd done that, "Show Referenced File in Finder" now works for all my images.